# Rotate canvas image while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement a `rotate` function for my photo editor. I'm relatively new working with `HTML5` elements, especially `canvas` elements.

Now, the image will rotate after clicking the button but it doesn't do it while maintaining the aspect ratio. To be specific as possible, I have included two images below: one before the rotation button was
clicked and one after that.

**BEFORE ROTATION:**
[image]

**AFTER ROTATION:**
[image]

As you can see, image does indeed rotate but it will crop majority of the image. Am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's what I've tried so far with results shown above:

```
function rotateImage(degrees, image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    if(degrees == 90 || degrees == 270) {
        canvas.width = image.height;
        canvas.height = image.width;
    } else {
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if(degrees == 90 || degrees == 270) {
        ctx.translate(image.height/2,image.width/2);
    } else {
        ctx.translate(image.width/2,image.height/2);
    }
    ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2 , -image.height / 2);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    $("#image").attr('src', dataURL);
}

document.getElementById("rotate").addEventListener("click", function() {
var el = this;
var data = el.getAttribute('data-value');
  var angleInDegrees = 0;

  if(data == 90) {
    angleInDegrees += 90 % 360;
  } else {
    if(angleInDegrees == 0) {
      angleInDegrees = 270;
    } else {
      angleInDegrees -= 90;
    }
  }
  // rotate the image based on degree value
  rotateImage(angleInDegrees, document.getElementById("canvas"));
});
```

**EDIT:**

Now, it does indeed rotate the image while maintaining the aspect ratio but only do it once. If rotate button is clicked again, it crops about 20% of the original image size. Few more pictures to demonstrate:

**BEFORE ROTATION**

[image]

**AFTER ROTATION BUTTON WAS CLICKED ONCE**
[image]

**AFTER ROTATION BUTTON WAS CLICKED AGAIN**
[image]

**Modified function**

```
function rotateImage(degrees, image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    if(degrees == 90 || degrees == 270) {
        canvas.width = image.height;
        canvas.height = image.width;
    } else {
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();

    if(degrees == 90 || degrees == 270) {
        ctx.translate(image.height/2,image.width/2);
    } else {
        ctx.translate(image.width/2,image.height/2);
    }
    ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2 , -image.height / 2);
    ctx.restore();

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    image.setAttribute('src', dataURL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made a few changes to your code.

1. `if(data == "90")` instead of `if(data == 90)` because it's a string
2. I've added [ctx.save()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [ctx.restore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) around the transformations

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


let cw = canvas.width = image.width;
let ch = canvas.height = image.height;

ctx.drawImage(image, 0 , 0);



function rotateImage(degrees, image) {

    if(degrees == 90 || degrees == 270) {
        cw = image.height;
        ch = image.width;
    } else {
        cw = image.width;
        ch = image.height;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.save()
    ctx.translate(cw/2,ch/2);
    ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2 , -image.height / 2);
    ctx.restore();
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    image.setAttribute('src', dataURL);
}

rotate.addEventListener("click", function() {
var el = this;
var data = el.dataset.value; console.log(data)
  var angleInDegrees = 0;

  if(data == "90") {
    angleInDegrees += 90 % 360;
  } else {
    if(angleInDegrees == 0) {
      angleInDegrees = 270;
    } else {
      angleInDegrees -= 90;
    }
  }


  // rotate the image based on degree value
  rotateImage(angleInDegrees, image);
});
```

Comment: Tried it without a luck. Now it resizes image while rotating until certain point when it just rotates but obviously I don't want to lose 90% of the original image. 

It's a bit tricky since all of the elements this "editor" uses are dynamically created inside this JS file.

Comment: Actually now it does work, but only when rotation button is clicked once. Check my edited post for images.